# Installing Opencv on remote connection

Tags: python, opencv, pip

Installing Opencv on Ubunto server using the remote connection, 
cmd Line: pip install opencv-python
getting error msg
ERROR: Exceptio                                                                                        n:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/co                                                                                        ntrib/pyopenssl.py", line 313, in recv_into
    return self.connection.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line                                                                                         1822, in recv_into
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line                                                                                         1622, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise WantReadError()
OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError

why receiving this error msg

Comment: Is the network in Ubuntu server kind of protected? The error message is very clear, your certificate cannot be read.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic, this is a network/sysadmin issue, not a python problem